# Using Cornerstone, how do I ignore Xcode's UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file?

Tags: xcode, svn, cornerstone

I'm using Cornerstone 2.7.12 and Xcode 5.1. Mostly I use Xcode's Source Control menu items but in this particular working copy I'm having trouble with UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate. I can commit just fine. Then, for example, I try to switch branches but Xcode complains that I have uncommitted changes. When I commit, the only thing that's changed is UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate. So I commit. Then I try to switch again but again Xcode complains about uncommitted changes. Again it's UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate.

So I thought I'd do the switch with Cornerstone (right-click on the Working Copy -> Switch...). In Cornerstone I've added `*.xcuserstate` to the Global Ignores (Cornerstone -> Preferences -> Subversion -> turn off Use default global ignores -> add "*.xcuserstate") but it doesn't ignore it. I've quit and restarted.

Using Cornerstone, how do I ignore Xcode's UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did:

- in Terminal cd to the project.workspace directory
- `svn -v status` revealed this file was under version control (M):

  M              655      654 user       xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
- `svn delete --keep-local --force xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`

That fixed it. At that point Cornerstone showed that it was ignoring the file. And Xcode behaved properly too.

Comment: The issue is that Cornerstone/SVN can't ignore files that are already committed to the repository. In addition to the suggested "svn delete" command above, I had to commit these deletes - which give them the status "Unversioned", and after that I was able to ignore these files with Cornerstone.